# Menu item opening and closing event

Tags: c#, wpf, event-handling, wpf-controls, menuitem

I want to handle an event, whenever the Submenus of a menu item opens. Same for closing. how can I do this?

Answer (score 17):

Very easy.  Subscribe to a `MenuItem`'s `SubmenuOpened` event.  Traditional way to do it:

```
MidItem.SubmenuOpened += new RoutedEventHandler(MidItem_SubmenuOpened);

private void MidItem_SubmenuOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //Menu Open Logic Here
}
```

Or the cool dynamic method:

```
MidItem.SubmenuOpened += delegate(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //Menu Open Logic Here
};
```

Comment: it `Opened`, not `Opening`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you want, but take a look at these events for `ContextMenu` and `MenuItem`:

`ContextMenu`:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contextmenu_events.aspx

`MenuItem`:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.menuitem_events.aspx

I think `ContextMenuOpening` and `ContextMenuClosing` might be interesting ;)

Comment: The problem with these is that they fire only when the menu/contextmenus are **actually** opened. In some scenarios you might want to also check when it **should** open (like a main menu that's hovered over when a previous menu was open) and these events don't capture that. Unfortunately I don't think there's a way to handle those events except to completely rewrite the control behavior.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish a opening BEFORE the real opening, you can subclass the menuitem

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Public Class CustomMenuItem
    Inherits MenuItem

    Public Event SubMenuOpening(sender As Object, e As CancelEventArgs)
    Public Event SubMenuClosing(sender As Object, e As CancelEventArgs)
    Protected Overrides Sub OnPropertyChanged(e As DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
        If e.Property Is MenuItem.IsSubmenuOpenProperty Then
            Dim MyCancelEventArgs As New CancelEventArgs
            If e.NewValue Then
                RaiseEvent SubMenuOpening(Me, MyCancelEventArgs)
                If MyCancelEventArgs.Cancel Then Me.IsSubmenuOpen = False
            Else
                RaiseEvent SubMenuClosing(Me, MyCancelEventArgs)
                If MyCancelEventArgs.Cancel Then Me.IsSubmenuOpen = True
            End If
        End If
        MyBase.OnPropertyChanged(e)
    End Sub

End Class
```

I know this is VB, but it's easily convertible.
Plus, with the CancelEventArgs, you can simulate cancel the opening (or closing).

Comment: The question has C# tag, not the VB